# How to retrieve nodes named from firebase Realtime database into RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am developing an app that has a list of prayers under which I have more nodes and those nodes have more nodes, how do I retrieve only the node list and not the data inside the node?

[image: 1]

For example in the above image, I have a prayers node, I want to retrieve only the children node from that i.e. "children" and "discipline" and not the data that is inside the two nodes.
after getting the data I want to set it into my recycler view.

note: Social node will have more nodes under it other than children and discipline which I have not yet added. I will want to get those as well.

Fragment where the recycler view will be shown:

```
public class PrayerSocialFragment extends Fragment {


    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    SocialAdapter socialAdapter;
    ArrayList<SocialModel> socialList;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_affimation_social, container, false);


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.prayer_recycler);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Data").child("Prayers").child("Social");
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

        socialList = new ArrayList<>();
        socialAdapter = new SocialAdapter(getApplicationContext(), socialList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(socialAdapter);

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                        SocialModel socialModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(SocialModel.class);
                        socialList.add(socialModel);
                }
                socialAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });


        return view;


    }
}
```

Model class:

```
public class SocialModel {

    String Social;

    public SocialModel() {
    }

    public SocialModel(String social) {
        Social = social;
    }

    public String getSocial() {
        return Social;
    }
}
```

Adapter class:

```
public class SocialAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SocialAdapter.MySocialViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<SocialModel> socialList;

    public SocialAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SocialModel> socialList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.socialList = socialList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MySocialViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.prayer_item_view, parent, false);
        return new MySocialViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MySocialViewHolder holder, int position) {

        SocialModel socialModel = socialList.get(position);
        holder.socialOpt.setText(socialModel.getSocial());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return socialList.size();
    }

    public static class MySocialViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        Button socialOpt;

        public MySocialViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            socialOpt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.prayer_cat2);


        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the data under the "prayers" node, for example, the "Children" and the "Discipline" keys, then please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference socialRef = db.child("Data").child("Prayers").child("Social");
socialRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String key = ds.getKey();
                Log.d("TAG", key);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
Children
Discipline
```

If you want to display those strings in a RecylerView, then you have to create an adapter class of type String and pass a `List<String>` rather than a `List<SocialModel>`.